# Need syntax to run program Ged2gwb inside Geneweb App

Tags: 18.04, webapps

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS on a Dell desktop with much success.

I've installed [Geneweb](https://geneweb.tuxfamily.org/wiki/GeneWeb) genealogy program and want to:

- convert a Gedcom file to Geneweb format using `ged2gwb` command
- load result into Geneweb
- load .gwb file when created in Ubuntu

What is the syntax to do this?

Comment: Have you tried this guide: http://cristal.inria.fr/~ddr/GeneWeb/en/start.htm

Answer (score 0):

https://geneweb.tuxfamily.org/wiki/ged explains the syntax and its options; the simplest command would be

```
ged2gwb IMPORTME.ged -o OUTPUTFILE
```

where you replace IMPORTME.ged  with the GED file to import from and OUTPUTFILE as the file to output to.